# How to get the "Page type" for the current page. EPiServer

Tags: types, episerver, current-page

How can I get the Page Type for the current page. I tried

```
CurrentPage.GetType();
```

but no success. I need to check if the Page Type equals a specific type in order to do something or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to check the `PageTypeName` or `PageTypeID` properties, like this:

```
if(CurrentPage.PageTypeName == "StartPage")
    // Do something
```

Check the reference: http://sdk.episerver.com/library/cms5/html/AllMembers_T_EPiServer_Core_PageData.htm

The `GetType()` method is declared on `System.Object` and returns the `System.Type` for the object. Is is available on all types in the .NET Framework since all types inherit from `System.Object`.

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have a site with both EPiServer Pages and Non-EpiServer Pages, the problem is that when checking the type on a Non-EpiServer Page "CurrentPage" returns values as if I was in the start page. I need to check if the page is an EpiServer page or not. Thanks

Comment: Your EPiServer pages probably inherit from a certain base class while the other pages dont, right? Just check `if(this is MyEpiPageBaseClass)` in the page and you should be fine.

Answer (score 5):

With a page type builder strongly typed class you can use the C# [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword

e.g

```
if (CurrentPage is SomeStronglyTypeClass)
```

Answer (score 3):

CurrentPage.PageTypeName gives you the name of the PageType

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Page Type Builder you can also use the PageTypeResolver class.